# Border an array of words in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, counting

I've been learning Bash and my teacher made an exercise that got me puzzled.

I'm just struggling with adding the spaces in front of the words.

The code should account for the number of characters in each word and adjust the number of asterisks and spacing for it to always be aligned.

This is what it should look like:

```
***********
* Hello   *
* World   *
* good    *
* etceter *
***********
```

My code:

```
#determine biggest word
words=("Hello" "World" "good" "etceter")
numchar=0
for i in ${words[@]}; do
    if [ ${#i} -gt $numchar ]
    then
        numchar=${#i}
    fi
done

#write *
a=-4
while [ $a -lt $numchar ]; do
    printf "*"
    ((a++))
done

#write array
echo
for txt in ${words[@]}; do
    space=$(($numchar-${#txt}))
    s=0
    echo "* $txt "
    while [ $s -lt $space ]; do
        printf " "
        ((s++))
        printf "*"
    done
done

#write *
a=-4
while [ $a -lt $numchar ]; do
    printf "*"
    ((a++))
done
```

I'm struggling with the #write array part.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a number of places here where you haven't properly double-quoted variable references, which can cause weird problems sometimes. I recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fixing (or at least understanding) what it points out -- it'll save you learning a lot of bad scripting habits.

Comment: The first `for` loop can be replace by `numchar=$(printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}" | wc -L)` if GNU `wc`(1) is available/acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a few changes.

```
#write array
echo
for txt in ${words[@]}; do
    space=$(($numchar-${#txt}))
    s=0
    echo -n "* $txt "           # -n added to not append a newline
    while [ $s -lt $space ]; do
        echo -n " "             # switched from printf to echo (cosmetics)
        ((s++))
        # printf "*"            # commented out
    done
    echo "*"                    # added
done
```

Your `while` loop only adds the spaces after the current word. The trailing `*` comes after the loop to finish this line.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Is here any reason to chose "echo -n" over "printf"?
Would you have any other suggestions to make the code my code better?

Comment: `printf` is more portable than `echo` in conjunction with other shells if you want to avoid trailing spaces. However, the correct syntax of `printf` is longer: `printf "%s" "*"`. You may have noticed that you are repeating the code (`write *`) to output the line with `*`. You could move this code to a function and then call the function at the required points.

Comment: Yes, I looked it up and fixed it, should I edit my main post with the fixed code?

Comment: No, please leave your original question unchanged. Thank you.

Comment: Despite it being more verbose, I'll always prefer `printf` over `echo -n`. I once had a bunch of my scripts break because an OS update changed the default behavior of `echo -n` to print the "-n" as part of its output, so I learned not to rely on `echo` for anything nontrivial. BTW, you can just use `printf " "` and `printf "*"` (no `"%s"` needed), since those strings don't contain `%` or `\`. When printing the word, though, you should use the full `printf "%s"` version.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the last 3 sections:

```
# define solid string of asterisks

printf -v stars  '*%.0s' $(seq 1 $(( numchar + 4)) )    # length = numchar + 4

echo "${stars}"

for txt in "${words[@]}"
do
    printf "* %-*s *\n" "${numchar}" "${txt}"
done

echo "${stars}"
```

This generates:

```
***********
* Hello   *
* World   *
* good    *
* etceter *
***********
```

Comment: You can have a single printf in the loop : `printf "* %-*s *\n" $numchar "$txt"`

Answer (score 0):

It's hardcoded a bit but think you got the idea:

```
$ echo '***********'; printf '* %-8s*\n' "${words[@]}"; echo '***********'
***********
* Hello   *
* World   *
* good    *
* etceter *
***********
```

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right track with getting the length of the longest line first.

Borders and padding can be done entirely with `printf` format specifiers, and pattern substitution. Use `%-Ns` to align left, and `%Ns` to align right.

With correct quoting, you can also have multiple words and spaces in each line.

Here's an example:

```
lines=('Hello World!'
       'Line two.'
        a-line
       'another line'
       'The end.')

# border character
c='*'

# get length of longest line, required for padding
for i in "${lines[@]}"; do
    ((${#i} > pad)) &&
    pad=${#i}
done

# make a string to fill top/bottom
fill=$(printf %$((pad + 4))s "$c")
fill=${fill// /$c}

# print the text box
printf '%s\n' "$fill"

for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    printf "$c %-${pad}s $c\n" "$line"
done

printf '%s\n' "$fill"
```

Output:

```
****************
* Hello World! *
* Line two.    *
* a-line       *
* another line *
* The end.     *
****************
```